# Euler's integral problem

Tags: calculus

Express this integral through Euler's integral.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\ln \frac1x\right)^pdx, \ \ \ (p>-1)$$

I tried taking $u=\ln\frac1x$, then $du=-\frac1x$ but it doesn't seem to help much. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: $$\ln\frac1x=\ln(x)^{-1}=-\ln x$$ and set $$\ln x=u$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You got your exponent in the wrong place there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $x=e^{-u}, dx=-e^{-u}du$ then it follows that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int _{0}^{1}\! \left( \ln  \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)  \right) ^{p}{dx}=&
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{(\ln(e^{u}))}^{p}{{\rm e}^{-u}}{du}\\
=&\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{u}^{p}{{\rm e}^{-u}}{du}\\
=&\Gamma  \left( p+1 \right) 
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: If $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ then it equals $p!$. Thanks for the great answer.